# Trying to show off emoji when it's added using Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Currently I'm trying to add something to my bot to display text and a preview when an emoji is added.
I was pretty close, but it appears the emoji doesn't exist on the server during the `emojiCreate` event.
my code (which is a mess) looks like this currently:

```js
var latestEmojiName = "";
let announcementChannel = "";
client.on("emojiCreate", emoji => {
  announcementChannel = emoji.guild.channels.find(x => x.id === "625678148440162314");
  announcementChannel.send("new emoji has been added:");
  latestEmojiName = emoji.name;
  newEmojiFollowup1();
});

function newEmojiFollowup1() {
  setTimeout(newEmojiFollowup2, 2000);
}

function newEmojiFollowup2() {
  announcementChannel.send(client.guilds.find(x => x.id === "607642928872947724").emojis.find(x => x.name === latestEmojiName));
}
```

Comment: What are the channels for the ids 625678148440162314 and 607642928872947724? Just to get a general idea of where you are looking and where you are posting.

Comment: The first one is a channel and the 2nd one is the guild id iirc

Comment: OK, I updated my response and got a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I added the following listener to one of my bots and it worked. Also, there is no need to look-up the guild because you do not need a timeout. The `emoji` object has all you need already.

You need to send: `<:${emoji.name}:${emoji.id}>`

Also, use `let` instead of `var` to resolve scoping issues and there is no need for all the "follow-on functions.

```js
// Verified with discord.js@11.5.1
const channelId = "625678148440162314" // e.g. Channel: #general
client.on("emojiCreate", emoji => {
  const channel = emoji.guild.channels.find(x => x.id === channelId)
  channel.send("A new emoji has been added:")
  channel.send(`<:${emoji.name}:${emoji.id}>`)
})
```

You can also send a rich-embed message:

```js
// Verified with discord.js@11.5.1
const channelId = "625678148440162314" // e.g. Channel: #general
client.on("emojiCreate", emoji => {
  const channel = emoji.guild.channels.find(x => x.id === channelId)
  const embed = new RichEmbed()
    .setTitle("A new emoji has been added!")
    .setColor(0x222222)
    .setDescription("Preview:")
  embed.addField(`:${emoji.name}:`, `<:${emoji.name}:${emoji.id}>`, true)
  channel.send(embed)
})
```

Comment: It looks like OP is using v11 which uses Collections rather than Managers.

Comment: @slothiful How did you infer that?

Comment: v11 would use `emoji.guild.channels.find()` rather than `emoji.guild.channels.cache.find()`. The former method doesn't exist for Managers.

Comment: @slothiful OK, noted. Thanks.